# Tic Tac toe game keeps getting invalid syntax

Tags: python

I was trying to make a tic tac toe game in python and invalid syntax keeps coming up on the line with `first.upper()` after the "1". I even moved the code around and it was still after "1". How do I fix my code?

```
first == input("Would u like to go first? 1 is Yes  2 is No \n")
if first.upper() == "1" 
    place == input("You are X where do u want to place it? \n")
```

Comment: `if first.upper() == "1":`

Comment: In other words, you left out the end colon in the `if` line.

Comment: You forgot the `:`, also, why are you checking if a string digit is uppercase?

Comment: Also, `first = input("Would u like to go first? 1 is Yes  2 is No \n")` (and the same goes for place). `==` is a comparison. also you should do `if first == "1\n"` or delete that `\n` after reading it.

Comment: Why `upper`? It's a *number*!

Answer (score 3):

In python, whenever you use an "if" statement, you must follow it up with ':' before going to the next line.
So it should be :

```
if first.upper() == "1":
    place == input("You are X where do u want to place it? \n")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
first = input("Would u like to go first? 1 is Yes  2 is No \n")
if first.upper() == 1: 
    place = input("You are X where do u want to place it? \n")
```

Try that